# for what value of $y$ does $\sum_{k= 0}^n a_0 x^k = \sum_{k=0}^n y^k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> for what value of $y$ does $$\sum_{k= 0}^n a_0 x^k = \sum_{k=0}^n y^k$$

This was just an idea I was playing around with. I tried solving

$$\frac{a_0(x^{n+1}-1)}{x-1} = \frac{y^{n+1}-1}{y-1} $$

This does not seem easy to solve algebraically.

It was easy enough for me to do as $n \to \infty$, as we get:

$$\frac{a_0}{1-x} = \frac1{1-y} \implies y = \frac{a_0 + x -1}{a_0}$$ However, I've had no luck in the finite case.

Comment: In the finite case, you simply have an equation of $n^{th}$ degree in $y$ to solve. I don't see the reason offhand why you'd expect "nice" solutions.

Comment: @dxiv: I don't necessarily expect a nice solution for the same reason you mentioned. I am more so checking to see if someone can find one, as I am curious.